# Filter a map in Angular2 with multiple keys

Tags: javascript, typescript

i have a Map as like below in a ts file. i need to filter the map by giving the multiple keys at a same time.

```
tMap: Map<string, number[]> = new Map<string, number[]>();
tMap.set('T',[1,2,3]);
tMap.set('U',[4,5,6]);
tMap.set('V',[4,5,6]);
```

my expected result will be excluding the  key "T". It should filter only U and V as a single array. please advise

Comment: Please reword this question. It's not remotely clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a new `Map` and insert filtered elements:

```
let newMap: Map<string, number[]> = new Map<string, number[]>();

tMap.forEach((value, key) => {
  if (key !== 'T') {
    newMap.set(key, value);
  }
});
```

Or just use `delete()` function of `Map`. If we suppose you have a list of keys to be deleted:

```
const deletedKeys = ['A', 'E', 'T'];

deletedKeys.forEach(key => tMap.delete(key));
```